# How can a text box automatically pic the date and time before submitting a form in asp.net c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a razor view, that submits a form to database. It has three textboxes to store the title, amount and Date.

Although it works properly, But I don't want to enter the date manually, I want the form to automatically pick the date and time while submitting a form in a hidden manner, not allowing the users to change the date and time while submitting the form.

This is the razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Request", "Requester", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.title, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.amount)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.date_and_time)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.date_and_time, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>
}
```

This is the model:

```
   public class Events
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_and_time { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: If you do not want to edit it, then do not include a form control for it

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay i will remove the form control, but how to insert the date and time automatically?

Comment: Just set it in the POST method before you save the record

Comment: @StephenMuecke the form method is already set to POST, can you be more specific ?

Comment: You will have to use JS to submit the form and manipulate the data while submitting it if you want real hour and minute time in controller's action. you can't preload the datetime value because user will spend some time to fill out the form. So, preloading it is not a good option if your requirement includes the hour minute part of a date time as well. please specify more what do you want to do with the date time.

Comment: I assume you want the `DateTime` property to be the current date/time, so just set that property to `DateTime.Now` before you save the record in your POST method (and you do not need js to submit the form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Do you mean something like this in the razor view, just above the button.                                                                                             
     Model.date_and_time = DateTime.Now;
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>

Comment: No. You set the value in your controller methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you

Comment: @StephenMuecke , inside the controller can i define it like below: var event_date = _context.evt.SingleOrDefault(a => a.submitted_on == DateTime.Now);

Comment: @JohnKamaal - that does not make much sense. Your database would not have any records that meet that condition - i.e. that were inserted at exactly the same time (and what is `submitted_on` vs `date_and_time`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke submitted_on is equal to date_and_time, sorry for the confusion. & now what is your solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183868/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-john-kamaal).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Request(Events event)
    {
        event.date_and_time = DateTime.Now();

        //then do other operations or just save it in the the database
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple approaches.

Approach 1

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.date_and_time)       
    <input type="datetime-local"...>
</div>
```

Approach 2

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.date_and_time, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control 
datepicker" })
</div>
```

Approach 2, unfortunately, only supports type "date". You may also consider using jquery datetimepicker or Bootstrap datetimepicker.